# getJson doesnt work when calling python script

Tags: javascript, python, html, getjson

I have the following simple code but getjson somehow doesnt work. 
My python script prints a json encoded value properly.
Can anyone suggest anything?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $.getJSON('weather.py', function(data) {
    console.log('callback works');
  });


   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
import json
from json import load
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pprint import pprint
import pycassa
from pycassa.pool import ConnectionPool
from pycassa.columnfamily import ColumnFamily
from pycassa.index import *

pool = pycassa.ConnectionPool('hr')
crime = pycassa.ColumnFamily(pool, 'crime')

##Pull all of the data and convert to JSON 
data = json.dumps([columns for key, columns in crime.get_range()])
return data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't run a python script from Jquery.

you need to have your python script running with a webserver to serve the response.

starting point : http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you indented your python script properly. I'll assume also that you already have a webserver environment configured. Besides that

Instead of

```
return data
```

you must

```
print data
```

In your python script. Since [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) will relay the output from your script and not the content of a variable you are returning.